# how to getting the string to a specified url?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4, nsurlconnection

Hi friends,

I am trying to get the string data and image data from a url.but the string data

displays null.And any one tell me how to upload the image to the specified url.

here i am writing this code

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage  imageWithData: [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://192.168.1.105:9966/PC/DisplayImage?id=2"]]];

myimages.image=image;
NSURL *url = [ NSURL URLWithString: [ NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://192.168.1.105:9966/PC/DisplayImage?id=2"] ]; 
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 90);
NSString *encodedImage = [Base64 encode:imageData];
NSLog(@"my encoding image is %@",encodedImage);
NSURL *url = [ NSURL URLWithString: [ NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://192.168.1.105:9966/PC/DisplayImage?id=2"] ]; 
NSString *test = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url];
NSLog(@"naveenkumar testing%@",test);
```

Comment: This isn't the cause, but you don't need `[NSString stringWithFormat:` when you are just using a static string. You can just use `[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://192...."]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use NSURLConnection for uploading image by using post method -

```
NSURL *postURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@submit.php",@"http://x.com/"]]; 

    NSMutableURLRequest *postRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:postURL
                                                               cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                                           timeoutInterval:30.0];

    // change type to POST (default is GET)
    [postRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    NSMutableData *postBody = [NSMutableData data];


    // just some random text that will never occur in the body
    NSString *stringBoundary = @"0xKhTmLbOuNdArY---This_Is_ThE_BoUnDaRyy---pqo";
    // header value
    NSString *headerBoundary = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",
                                stringBoundary];
    // set header
    [postRequest addValue:headerBoundary forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
// image ------------

        [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [postBody appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"text\"; filename=\"frontimage.png\"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [postBody appendData:[@"Content-Type: image/png\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [postBody appendData:[@"Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        // add it to body

        [postBody appendData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 90)];
        [postBody appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
// final boundary

    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


    // add body to post
    [postRequest setHTTPBody:postBody];

    NSURLConnection *theConnection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:postRequest delegate:self];

    if (theConnection) 
        NSLog(@"%@",theConnection);
```

Comment: hi friend i try this way but the problem is how to crate the php file by using xcode.is it possible Or directly download the php file

Comment: what is the need of creating php file through xcode. The file should be on server that will you call using NSURLConnection.